# Has an election ever been called off due to a terror attack?

Tags: democracy, terrorism

This morning, UK Prime Minister Theresa May [announced](http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-security-may-election-idUKKBN18V0HF) that the general election on June the 8th will go ahead despite the [London Bridge Terror Attack](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-06-03/london-bridge-closed-ambulances-on-scene-after-incident).

Is there a precedent of an election being called of or postponed due to terrorist related violence?

Comment: What hasn't been addressed (at least in anything I've seen) is whether there is any legal mechanism for delaying a U.K. general election.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I've edited the question to include this point, but I assume one of the answers can be declare martial law? Scrap this I will ask as a separate question since this is about any electionand we want to know about the UK.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19514/is-there-a-legal-way-to-postpone-or-call-of-a-general-election-in-the-uk-due-to?noredirect=1&lq=1 I've raised this point here.

Answer (score 2):

Israel had primary elections for the Israeli Labor Party delayed by 24 hours because of security concerns - it clashed with a Britney Spears concert, and the police couldn't provide security for both. Israel suffers from [terrorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict), so it is likely the security concerns for the elections were terrorism-related.

[Israel is postponing an election because of Britney Spears](https://twitter.com/i/moments/849756933624020992)

> Britney Spears is set to perform in Tel Aviv on July 3, which was the
>   same day Israeli Labor Party had planned to hold its leadership
>   election. But citing a lack of security to cover both events, the
>   election has now been pushed back 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite rare and after [doing a quick Wikipedia search](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&profile=default&search=election%20postponed%20terrorism&searchToken=626qs6fg98el3ykwmj6z80t9i) using the keywords – "election", "postponed" and "terrorism", only the 2015 Nigerian general election seems relevant.

Basically, Nigeria postponed its general election by 6 weeks in 2015 due to security fears and threats of violence.

As quoted from [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-31221545):

> Election commission chief Attahiru Jega said the delay until 28 March was necessary because of a lack of troops available to protect voters.
>
> Nigeria's military has been battling an insurgency by Boko Haram militants in the north-east of the country.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> The Boko Haram conflict has raged for five years but just days before the vote, Professor Jega was suddenly told the entire military would be focused solely on the north-east - in other words, "you are getting no help from the military, you are on your own". With the threat of violence so real, he was put in a tight corner.